# Error while using file_get_contents PHP function

Tags: php, javascript

I am using:

```
$myFile = SITE_URL.'/abc.html'; 
$template_msg = file_get_contents($myFile);
```

This code works on my local machine, but it doesn't work on the live site. It gives me a 500 page not found error.

Comment: is `SITE_URL` set correctly on `production` environment?

Comment: 500 is a internal server error. Maybe allow_url_fopen is set to false? Did you try CURL?

Comment: read logs, use php's realpath() to get the real file path

Comment: `500 page not found error` is a generic status code that the web server returns when the PHP script triggers an error. You should find the exact error message in the server logs (or configure PHP to log/display errors). I'd advise you against just guessing.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario actually, that would '500 internal server error' OR '404 page not found'. One is a client error (requesting a non existent resource), while the other is a server error (failed to handle request).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it can't .. (well, actually it can, but only on purpose, using the same header function you can set the response Status header to 404), what I want'ed to point out is simply that a "500 page not found error" does not exist ;)

Comment: @smassey - On my, I hadn't noticed that the question says *500 page not found error* and I had even copied the text verbatim xD

Answer (score 0):

Use this type of path.

echo $myFile; and check if it is like 'http://www.example.com/abc.html' this type of path then it working.

```
$myFile = SITE_URL.'/abc.html'; 
$template_msg = file_get_contents($myFile);
```

Hope it helps to you.